# Comparator ArrayList Objeto JSP

Tags: java, jsp, classificação, comparação, arraylist

Eu estou com dificuldades de implementar o método Comparator, para ordenar o ArrayList de Objetos.

Tenho uma class de Empreendimentos. Onde depois, eu crio um ArrayList, que é preenchido a partir de um sistema de gerenciador de conteúdo.

Adicionei o metodo compareTo, e ele ordena pelo atributo Area.
Mas agora eu também preciso que ordene por quantidade de quartos, e banheiros.

Como eu poderia fazer isso ?

Aqui esta o cidgo atual:

```
    <%! 
public class Empreendimento implements Comparable<Empreendimento>{

     //possui atributos, gets, sets e construtor

        public int compareTo(Empreendimento Emp) {
            if (this.menorArea < Emp.getMenorArea()) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (this.menorArea > Emp.getMenorArea()) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
%>
```

Depois que o gerenciador de conteudo, cria o ArrayList com esses obejtos.
Faço um filtro, e depois ordeno. Ai uso isso:

```
Collections.sort(ArrayResultadoBusca);
```

Comment: gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Com `Java 8`, há uma solução simples e limpa para lidar com multiplas comparações.

*Lambda*:

```
Comparator<Empreendimento> comparator = Comparator
        .comparing(e -> e.getMenorArea)
        .thenComparingInt(e -> e.getQuantidadeQuarto)
        .thenComparingInt(e -> e.getQuantidadeBanheiro);
```

*Method Reference*:

```
Comparator<Empreendimento> comparator = Comparator
        .comparing(Empreendimento::getMenorArea)
        .thenComparingInt(Empreendimento::getQuantidadeQuarto)
        .thenComparingInt(Empreendimento::getQuantidadeBanheiro);
```

> Não é recomendado misturar código `html` da `view` com código *Java*,
>   é interessante realizar a comparação em uma **classe** e depois passar
>   o resultado por uma [Expression Language](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_Express%C3%A3o) (EL).

Uma alternativa é implementar um `Comparator` que ao invez de passar os atributos por parametro, passa duas classes do mesmo tipo e compara seus atributos.

*Ex*:

```
Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<Empreendimento>(){
    public int compare(Empreendimento e1, Empreendimento e2) {
        int comparacao = e1.getMenorArea().compareTo(e2.getMenorArea());
        if(comparacao != 0) {
           return comparacao;
        }

        comparacao = e1.getQuantidadeQuarto().compareTo(e2.getQuantidadeQuarto());
        if(comparacao != 0) {
           return comparacao;
        }

        return e1.getQuantidadeBanheiro().compareTo(e2.getQuantidadeBanheiro());     
    }
});
```

É importante implementar o `equals` e `hashCode` na classe modelo, nesse caso *Empreendedorismo*.

Comment: Esse ultimo exemplo eu não entendi. Eu posso criar o compare dentro da class ? Pode ter vários compare ? Ex.: compareQuarto(), compareArea()... E depois fazer a chamada da ordenação ? Como ficaria a chamada da ordenação ? E na class Empreendimento, eu preciso usar o " implements Comparator " ?

Comment: Editei o post com as alterações. Você pode implementar se quiser, a classe anonima foi apenas para o exemplo.